Why might `git rev-list --objects` miss two blobs?
In a large repo, I recently ran the following commands:
git rev-list --objects <my_rev_list> RevListOut.txt

echo -e "<my_rev_list>" | git pack-objects --revs /tmp/XXX
git verify-pack -v /tmp/XXX-b569475c51d937df848abbcfe16433e2f8ebc0f5.pack > Unpack.txt

When I compared the objects in RevListOut.txt and Unpack.txt I discovered that there are exactly two objects in Unpack.txt that do not exist in RevListOut.txt, and they have the following shas:
380a0876f57a4708b4a73a29d2ace2d4506880a2
2000687bd2701ff5c7c37013178d15384f0deefa

I did some more investigation and found that both of these objects corresponds to files that are tracked by git.
Why might git rev-list --objects miss an object?

Mailing list https://lore.kernel.org/git/CAO8bsPBZzSWG9YL9q3hsStygy=DMYkAAJ6PVyP4id4RCcjzM6g@mail.gmail.com/T/#u

Checking the configs help got me to
   pack.useSparse
       When true, git will default to using the --sparse option in git
       pack-objects when the --revs option is present. This algorithm only
       walks trees that appear in paths that introduce new objects. This
       can have significant performance benefits when computing a pack to
       send a small change. However, it is possible that extra objects are
       added to the pack-file if the included commits contain certain types
       of direct renames. Default is true.

and notice the last two sentences there.

Nice! Confirmed that git config set pack.useSparse false makes the two commands capture the same set!
